# "Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3" error

Tags: indexeddb

I'm trying to do the following inside a function:

```
var transaction = db.transaction("CustDetails",IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
```

giving an error as below:

```
"Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 3"
```

I've done the following:
1. I've declared a global db.
2. the above transaction code is in a function and database open is in another function and being called from this function. 
3. However, i've declared the below globally.

```
var db;
var test = {};
test.indexedDB = {};
test.indexedDB.db = null;
```

After doing the following also i'm getting the error as written above. What could be the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create the structure first.

```
var conn = window.indexeddb.open("name", 1)
conn.onupgradeneeded =function (e){
   // Create the structure here
}
conn.onsuccess = function (e){
   db = e.target.result;
   db.transaction("CustDetails",IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
}
```

This [post](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2011/10/indexed-db-defining-database-structure.html) tells you how you can define your structure, but note that this uses the old way. And this [post](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/01/indexed-db-defining-your-structure-new.html) tells you how the new way works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, i've created the structure and have used onupgradeneeded also as below:                                                                 In initialize function i've the following:

Comment: I think a part of your comment is missing.